# SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthezised / python manage.py migrate

Tags: python, django, syntax-error, migrate

I'm really new in programming and I wanted to follow the Djangogirls tutorial, but I'm stucked now.
In the tutorial, I am [here](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_start_project/):

> To create a database for our blog, let's run the following in the console: python manage.py migrate (we need to be in the djangogirls directory that contains the manage.py file). If that goes well, you should see something like this: ...

There is no option to fail in the tutorial but I have an error message:

```
(myvenv) C:\Users\Julcsi\djangogirls> python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\Julcsi\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", 
line 364, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\Julcsi\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", 
line 338, in execute
django.setup()
File "C:\Users\Julcsi\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", 
line 27, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\Julcsi\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", 
line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "C:\Users\Julcsi\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", 
line 94, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "C:\Users\Julcsi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", 
line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 723, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_remove
File "C:\Users\Julcsi\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", 
line 4, in <module>
from django.contrib.admin.filters import (
File "C:\Users\Julcsi\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\filters.py", 
line 10, in <module>
from django.contrib.admin.options import IncorrectLookupParameters
File "C:\Users\Julcsi\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", 
line 12, in <module>
from django.contrib.admin import helpers, widgets
File "C:\Users\Julcsi\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\widgets.py", 
line 152
'%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items(),
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

What am I doing wrong? What should I do?

I have Python 3.7.0b1

Thanks a lot in advance for the help :)

Comment: You really shouldn't be using an unreleased version of Python. Stick to 3.6.

Comment: Thank you for  your reply! :) Unfortunately, after I uninstalled Python 3.7.0b1, when I try to "ask" in the command line wich version is active, it's still the 3.7. :(

Comment: I just got the same exact error with Python 3.6

Comment: Python 3.7 is released

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51265858/syntaxerror-generator-expression-must-be-parenthesized)

Answer (score 75):

You’re not doing anything wrong; this is a problem between Django and Python 3.7. [Django has a fix](https://github.com/django/django/commit/931c60c5216bd71bc11f489e00e063331cf21f40), but that fix hasn’t made it into a new version yet.

You can install the stable version of Python, Python 3.6, in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! :)

I tried to uninstall 3.7 but in Command line, I still see the Python 3.7 as the version used... I don't understand why.
I uninstalled Python 3.7. with the "python-3.7.0b1-amd64.exe" + Uninstall button. I cannot see it in my files. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Ohh, sorry, now I realized that the problem occures only in the 'myvenv' virtual environment (after I type in the "myvenv\Scripts\activate")

Comment: @julo6: Yeah, unfortunately the only sure way to deal with that is to delete the venv and make it again. (So if you already did that, it was the best option.)

Comment: Thank you so much! No, I didn't realized that I should have delete the venv and make it again... So your comment saved me :D Now it works! Thanks again!

Comment: As per https://github.com/django/django/commit/931c60c#commitcomment-30238549, this will never be fixed. Django 1.11 LTS and Python 3.7+ will be incompatible.

Comment: @hyperknot: The tutorial is kept up to date – installs 2.0.x now – so it’s fixed.

Comment: Django itself is not fixed, that's the core of the problem.

Answer (score 16):

This is [a known incompatibility](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28814) between Django and Python 3.7. A fix has already been merged into Django [2.x branches](https://github.com/django/django/commit/931c60c5) and backported into [1.11 branch](https://github.com/django/django/pull/10654/commits/568c2f45ef5).

To solve this issue, simply update Django to at least version [1.11.17 (or 2.x)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django) or you can downgrade Python to version 3.6.

Comment: That soved the issue I was having!

Answer (score 13):

Also, upgrading Django solved my problem

On your terminal,

```
$ pip install -U Django
```

or see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/upgrade-version/)

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Downgrading Python is also a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Only Django==2.2 will be supported to Python 3.7 so upgrading your Django Version will solve your problem

```
pip3 install django --upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Django Girls tutorial version in English](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/) has [just switched to Django 2.0](https://github.com/DjangoGirls/tutorial/pull/1282#event-1737255058) which should make it compatible to Python 3.7. (Django 2.0 includes [a backport](https://github.com/django/django/commit/931c60c) of the fix mentioned in [Ry-'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48822656/674064).)

So everyone beginning the tutorial now should be fine with Python 3.7.

If you've already begun the tutorial you'd have to start again at the [Django installation](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_installation) chapter. You'll want to do that in a new directory (either delete  or rename your current `djangogirls` directory or choose a different name for the new directory) as the files generated by

```sh
django-admin print startproject mysite .
```

depend on the Django version in use.

Comment: [Translations of the tutorial to other languages](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/) might need some time to catch up with that change. If you'd like to help with that, see [here](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/#would-you-like-to-help-us-translate-the-tutorial-into-other-languages).

Answer (score 1):

Per [Django's FAQ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django), Django 1.11.x is not compatible with Python 3.7.

Django 1.11.x reached [end of mainstream support](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions) on December 2, 2017 and it receives only data loss and security fixes until its end of life.

Answer (score 0):

As all of the above answers already suggesting that there's a miss match between Django and Python version.

 While creating a virtual environment, please run the following command

```
python3.6 -m venv myenv
```

It will use **Python3.6** while creating your virtual environment.
Now you can install all the dependencies in this virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue solved by **upgrading Django to Dajngo==1.11.29**, the last release of Dajngo 1.11. I think my python version was 3.8.x. Give it a try if you are not planning to upgrade to Django 2.x or 3.x

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below-mentioned steps to fix the issue:

- Move to the directory where you have installed the `virtualenv`
- You will find a directory named lib. Inside that directory, you will find a directory named pythonx.y where x.y is the version of python you are using
- Now, go to `site-packages`
- Then go to the directory `django`
- Move to `contrib` directory
- Now, go to `admin` directory. This is where you would find a python file `widgets.py`
- Find the following code snippet in that file

```
            if params:
                related_url += '?' + '&amp;'.join(
                related_url += '?' + '&amp;'.join('%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items())
                    '%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items(),
                )
```

You need to change that to the following

```
            if params:
                related_url += '?' + '&amp;'.join(
                related_url += '?' + '&amp;'.join('%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items())
```

Save the changes and execute the migrate again.

Comment: Changing a 3rd party library's source code is not a good idea. better to upgrade to a version of Django that supports the python version