# SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized

Tags: python, django

I just installed django and after installing that I created a django project and  was trying to run django server by command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

After that I'am getting error as:
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Post the code that generates the error. But the error is quite self explaining.

Comment: Post the content in `admin\widgets.py` around line `151`...

Comment: Which python version you are using? 2.7 or 3.4/5? And which Django version you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthezised / python manage.py migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822571/syntaxerror-generator-expression-must-be-parenthezised-python-manage-py-migra)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

**TL; DR: Upgrade Django to version 1.11.17+ or 2.0+**

---

This error [is a known incompatibility](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28814) related to [Python issue #32012](https://bugs.python.org/issue32012). Projects based on Django 1.11.16 and below will raise this exception when started with Python 3.7. A patch for this issue [has been merged into Django 2.0 and 2.1 branches](https://github.com/django/django/commit/931c60c5) and cherry-picked later into [Django 1.11.17](https://github.com/django/django/pull/10654/commits/568c2f45ef5).

Note: Python 3.7 is officially supported by [Django 1.11.17](https://docs.djangoproject.com/id/2.1/releases/1.11.17/) and above, including [any 2.x branch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django).

Comment: That last part, updating to `1.11.17`, worked perfectly.

Comment: That also soved the issue I was having!

Comment: Confirm I had exactly the same issue and fix helped - upgraded django version from `1.11.9` => `1.11.17`

Answer (score 25):

Generator expression must be parenthesized

**> Update Django version to 1.11.17**

```
pip install django==1.11.17
```

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue. This is how I changed to django version 2.0 and used python3

- $pip3 install django==2.0
- $python3 manage.py runserver

Answer (score 2):

1. Install this version: `pip install django==1.11.17`
2. Run cmd.
3. go to your project folder.
4. `python manage.py runserver`
5. it will give a URL for server and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the version incompatibility.Just we need to upgrade the Django version to 2.1.
Run the command in cmd:Pip install django==2.1. this will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I just faced an Error like this. I was using Django-1.11.10. I deleted it and installed Django 2.0

Problem is solved.

But if you are using ForeignKey in you model.py files it must be problem again. You should update your coding to 2.0 versiong insted of older versiyon.

**Example:**

django older version

```
user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='posts')
```

django 2.0

```
user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I realized it is due to the compatibility of the Django version I was working with. So I had to state the Python version explicitly like this: `>python3.6 manage.py runserver`

Answer (score -1):

Just open file: 
`venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py` 
and replace the lines

```
related_url += '?' + '&amp;'.join(
    '%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items(),)
```

with

```
related_url += '?' + '&amp;'.join('%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items())
```

Comment: it work for me i upgrade my django project to 1.11 and i try to makemigrations and it give this errors and i try to change the code in to the one above and i try to migrate again and it work for so try it.

Comment: This is a really bad idea -- you're changing core Django code, and now have to guarantee that your "custom" copy of Django is installed wherever your site is installed.