# Django Runserver error while executing "Python manage.py runserver"

Tags: python, django

```
C:\Users\SRIRAM_CHIVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\FirstDjango
Proj>python manage.py runserver
Exception ignored in thread started by: <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper
at 0x00000000038D00D0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SRIRAM_CHIVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-pa
ckages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SRIRAM_CHIVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-pa
ckages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\SRIRAM_CHIVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-pa
ckages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Users\SRIRAM_CHIVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-pa
ckages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\SRIRAM_CHIVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-pa
ckages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SRIRAM_CHIVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-pa
ckages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\SRIRAM_CHIVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-pa
ckages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\SRIRAM_CHIVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-pa
ckages\django\apps\config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\SRIRAM_CHIVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importl
ib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\SRIRAM_CHIVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-pa
ckages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.filters import (
  File "C:\Users\SRIRAM_CHIVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-pa
ckages\django\contrib\admin\filters.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.options import IncorrectLookupParameters
  File "C:\Users\SRIRAM_CHIVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-pa
ckages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin import helpers, widgets
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized (widgets.py, line 152)
```

Django version installed successfully-1.11.10
python version-3.8.1

Project created and manage.py as well created.

BUt while i am trying runserver,Throwing an error with this this big passage:
Help me out how can i solve this?

Comment: try with python 3.7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51265858/syntaxerror-generator-expression-must-be-parenthesized)

Comment: Sorry will you elaborate please

Answer (score 0):

The same happened with me also, but this issue is a minor one as it happens if you have multiple versions of Python on your system, you can select a specific Python version by running `python3` or whichever version you want. So you should start from the beginning, uninstall Django first, then create a virtual environment, decide upon a directory where you want to place it, and run the `venv` module as a script with the directory path:

```sh
python3 -m venv tutorial-env
```

This will create the tutorial-env directory if it doesn’t exist, and also create directories inside it Once you’ve created a virtual environment, you may activate it.

On Windows, run:

```
tutorial-env\Scripts\activate.bat
```

On Unix or MacOS, run:

```sh
source tutorial-env/bin/activate
```

Now, In the command prompt, ensure your virtual environment is active, and execute the following command:

```sh
py -m pip install Django
```

**NOTE:** If `django-admin` only displays the help text no matter what arguments it is given, there is probably a problem with the file association in Windows. Check if there is more than one environment variable set for running Python scripts in `PATH`. This usually occurs when there is more than one Python version installed.