# New to Python - Django, Need To Read Log

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have been handed over an application which is built in Python - Django. I need to support it. There was no handover or anything like that. Pitty Me!
I am new to this language and framework. When I try to run the server with `python manage.py runserver` I get following errors:

> Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x108f48e18>
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/atariq/Sites/Python_Stuff/123/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/atariq/Sites/Python_Stuff/123/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
>       autoreload.raise_last_exception()
>     File "/Users/atariq/Sites/Python_Stuff/123/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
>       six.reraise(*_exception)
>     File "/Users/atariq/Sites/Python_Stuff/123/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
>       raise value.with_traceback(tb)
>     File "/Users/atariq/Sites/Python_Stuff/123/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/atariq/Sites/Python_Stuff/123/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 27, in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>     File "/Users/atariq/Sites/Python_Stuff/123/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
>       app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
>     File "/Users/atariq/Sites/Python_Stuff/123/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
>       module = import_module(entry)
>     File "/Users/atariq/Sites/Python_Stuff/123/venv/lib/python3.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>     File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
>     File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>     File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>     File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>     File "", line 728, in exec_module
>     File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>     File "/Users/atariq/Sites/Python_Stuff/123/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/**init**.py", line 4, in 
>       from django.contrib.admin.filters import (
>     File "/Users/atariq/Sites/Python_Stuff/123/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/filters.py", line 10, in 
>       from django.contrib.admin.options import IncorrectLookupParameters
>     File "/Users/atariq/Sites/Python_Stuff/123/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 12, in 
>       from django.contrib.admin import helpers, widgets
>     File "/Users/atariq/Sites/Python_Stuff/123/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py", line 152
>       '%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items(),
>       ^

I am unable to understand what it says. Can someone guide me over it?
I have installed all the required packages for the project with pip.

I am on Python 3.7 and using virtualenv.

**UPDATE**

I came to know that project works with Python 3.6, so I installed it and still getting same type of error log.
Pip Freeze gave me this:

```
asgiref==1.1.2
attrs==18.2.0
autobahn==18.11.2
Automat==0.7.0
certifi==2018.11.29
channels==1.1.6
chardet==3.0.4
constantly==15.1.0
coreapi==2.3.3
coreschema==0.0.4
daphne==1.3.0
defusedxml==0.5.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==1.11.12
django-allauth==0.32.0
django-cors-headers==2.4.0
django-debug-toolbar==1.9.1
django-filter==2.0.0
django-jsonview==1.2.0
django-prometheus==1.0.13
django-pyodbc-azure==1.11.12.1
django-watchman==0.15.0
djangorestframework==3.7.7
djangorestframework-camel-case==0.2.0
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
djangorestframework-xml==1.3.0
docutils==0.13.1
drf-yasg==1.6.2
future==0.17.1
gevent==1.2.2
greenlet==0.4.15
hyperlink==18.0.0
idna==2.7
incremental==17.5.0
inflection==0.3.1
itypes==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
ldap3==2.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
oauthlib==2.1.0
openapi-codec==1.3.2
Pillow==5.3.0
prometheus-client==0.5.0
pyasn1==0.4.4
Pygments==2.3.0
PyHamcrest==1.9.0
PyJWT==1.7.1
pyodbc==4.0.23
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2018.7
raven==6.7.0
requests==2.20.1
requests-oauthlib==1.0.0
ruamel.yaml==0.15.81
six==1.11.0
sqlparse==0.2.4
Twisted==18.9.0
txaio==18.8.1
ua-parser==0.8.0
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.24.1
user-agents==1.1.0
uWSGI==2.0.17
zope.interface==4.6.0
```

Manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ProjectName.settings.development")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Regards

Comment: What Django version do you use? Could you share from `pip freeze`?

Comment: Updated the question after your comment.

Comment: You are using Django 1.11.12. Only Django 1.11.17 started to be compatible with Python 3.7. 
Info from official Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django
I suggest to use Python 3.6 if you need Django 1.11 or update Django to 2 version.

Comment: As far as you installed python 3.6 did you recreated virtual env and installed all those packages there again?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be incompatibility of Python 3.7 and your current version of Django. You can find more details in [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822571/syntaxerror-generator-expression-must-be-parenthezised-python-manage-py-migra) question
What I can suggest is to upgrade your Django 2 or use Python 3.6.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django) you can see that Python 3.7 is compatible with Django 1.11.17 version.

Comment: Your answer helped.

Comment: If it helped, could you please mark my answer as a solution? Thanks! Good luck!

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. Answer I have posted myself.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the code u a=have written in `manage.py`
Who ever tries python for the first tym they does a very basic mistake of inidnantion. Though it ll be inditnation error for sometime it will throw some other prioritized error. !CHECK FOR INDINANATION

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the help.

After a lot of headbang, I came to know that there were a lot of modules missing from req.txt file which were required to build the project. They were mentioned in some other file.

After installing all the required modules, and running the migrations, I was able to run the project.