# Python3 commmands not working in my virtual environment

Tags: python, django, macos, virtual-environment

I have Python-3.8.1 installed in my virtual environment, but still the default version is Python-2.7 only (because of MacOS)

Now, whenever I try to run a command starting with `python3`, such as  `python3 manage.py startapp ...` or `python3 manage.py runserver`, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

[image]

Comment: What virtual environment are you using?

Comment: Please add the complete error in your question

Comment: Hi @HeisAif, I used "conda create --name myDjangoEnv django" to create my virtual environment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthezised / python manage.py migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822571/syntaxerror-generator-expression-must-be-parenthezised-python-manage-py-migra)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an older version of Django? Based on [this](https://github.com/django/django/commit/931c60c#commitcomment-30238549) Django 1.11 and Python 3.7+ are incompatible.

To upgrade your django package, first switch to your virtual environment:

`conda activate your-django-env-name`

Then run the following command to get the latest version on your virtual environment:

`pip install django --upgrade`

Comment: Hi @Winston, yes, my Django version is 1.11.29 and it is installed in the Python2 folder.....Now, how do I install the latest version of Django, like 3.x, in the Python3 folder??

Comment: First, switch to your venv using `conda activate myDjangoEnv`, then run `pip3 install django --upgrade` to get the latest version.

Comment: upgrading the django version may break the application itself, its better to use older version of python (version 3.6) which supports django being used.

Comment: Ok! It seems like he is just starting the project and creating apps in which case using the latest version is the better choice!

Comment: Agree, if using an already existing project or following a tutorial with a particular version of django, better use the required django, else using latest version of django is better option.

Answer (score 0):

1. To create an environment with a specific version of Python:

`conda create -n myenv python=3.6`

2. To create an environment with a specific package:

`conda create -n myenv django=1.11.29`

For your use case I suggest:

`conda create -n myDjangoEnv python=3.6 django=1.11.29`

First activate the conda environment before running any commmand:

`conda activate myDjangoEnv`

You won't be required to type 'python3', simply use 'python'.

Comment: Since you already have an environment named 'myDjangoEnv', try making a new environment using method in answer and see If the error gets solved.