# Can any one have a solution of my problem i am trying to run django server in ubuntu 20.04 but failed to run

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have created env variable and installed python3 after that install django server successfully but i am getting error and unable to received any port nor ip from the server. my concern is failed to run the django server. Error code is below

```
env) (base) developer@MCA:~/django-apps/project/myapp$ python manage.py runserver
Exception ignored in thread started by: <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fdb26e420d0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/developer/django-apps/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/django-apps/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/developer/django-apps/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/developer/django-apps/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/developer/django-apps/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/django-apps/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/developer/django-apps/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/developer/django-apps/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/developer/django-apps/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.filters import (
  File "/home/developer/django-apps/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/filters.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.options import IncorrectLookupParameters
  File "/home/developer/django-apps/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin import helpers, widgets
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized (widgets.py, line 151)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthezised / python manage.py migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822571/syntaxerror-generator-expression-must-be-parenthezised-python-manage-py-migra)

Comment: You're using an old version of Django with a version of python that is too new for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you follow the steps from here you will fix it :
[here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)